# How to add two middlewares in controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel-5

What would be the correct way to add these two middleware in the Controller constructor.

`Route::get('admin', ['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'], function()`

I have the following which is clearly incorrect.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth','admin');
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can break it down to two statements as below

```
public function __construct()
{
      $this->middleware('auth');
      $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Or if you want to use one statement

```
public function __construct()
{
      $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);
}
```

However if you restrict the middleware for certain methods like below

```
 $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin'], ['except' => [
            'fooAction',
            'barAction',
        ]]);
```

In that case, you restrict both **auth** and **admin** for  `fooAction` method and `barAction` method

Source:

> https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware